# Navigation Bar inside a dashboard:

Tags: javascript, html, angular, navbar, dashboard

I was wondering about what a better practice to add the nav side bar to my project, since its an angular2 im using components, so my dashboard has a main wrapper thats splits the content and and navbar itself.
both should be components.

now, when i want to navigate to other component, I can:
1. use a link to other component that holds the **same navbar** (duplicate code)
OR
2. change the html page to show another component (dynamic switching when click only for the content)

what do you think ? thanks!

Comment: If you are using angular, what you need is angularjs ui-router

Comment: I think you are mistake since UI-ROUTER is for angularjs, it has a version for angular 2, but the native router is better